# Adjusting the Tikz control-figure connections

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have this problem with my Tikz figure:

[image]

As you can see, the different labels stay very close together and even get inside some blocks, as you can correct that to try to make the whole set as equidistant as possible

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,arrows.meta,positioning,quotes}
\newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=4em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
        \node [input, name=input] {};
        \node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
        \node [block, right of=sum] (controller) {$\frac{1}{Ls+R}$};
        \node [block, right of=controller] (kt) {$k_t$};
        \node [block, right of=kt, node distance=2cm] (system) {$sist$};

        \node [output, right of=system] (output) {};
        \node [block, below of=kt] (measurements) {$k_e$};

        \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$V(s)$} (sum);
        \draw [->] (sum) -- node {} (controller);
        \draw [->] (controller) -- node {$I(s)$} (kt);
        \draw [->] (kt) -- node[name=u] {$T(s)$} (system);
        \draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$\Omega(s)$}(output);
        \draw [->] (y) |- (measurements);
        \draw [->] (measurements) -| node[pos=1.00] {$-$} 
        node [near end] {$E(s)$} (sum);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    
\end{document}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhVmn.png
```

Answer (score 1):

You load the `positioning` package, but don't use its facilities.

- Instead of `right of=xxx`, write `right=of xxx`, and likewise the rest.
- Instead of `right=of sum`, write `right=of input`.

Now the boxes are equally and symmetrically spaced. For additional adjustements,

- change `node distance` for global changes.
- use `right=15mm of xxx` for individual changes.
- If needed, there are also `xshift=...` and `yshift=...`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,arrows.meta,positioning,quotes}
\newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=4em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
        \node [input, name=input] {};
        \node [sum, right=of input] (sum) {};
        \node [block, right=of input] (controller) {$\frac{1}{Ls+R}$};
        \node [block, right=of controller] (kt) {$k_t$};
        \node [block, right=of kt] (system) {$sist$};

        \node [output, right=of system] (output) {};
        \node [block, below=of kt] (measurements) {$k_e$};

        \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$V(s)$} (sum);
        \draw [->] (sum) -- node {} (controller);
        \draw [->] (controller) -- node {$I(s)$} (kt);
        \draw [->] (kt) -- node[name=u] {$T(s)$} (system);
        \draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$\Omega(s)$}(output);
        \draw [->] (y) |- (measurements);
        \draw [->] (measurements) -| node[pos=1.00] {$-$} 
        node [near end] {$E(s)$} (sum);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With se of the `calc` and `chains` libraries for positioning of diagram nodes is possible to make code for control diagram significant shorter:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                positioning,
                quotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 6mm and 12mm,
  start chain = going right,
%
  dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, outer sep=0pt,
                node contents={}},
  box/.style = {draw, minimum height=2em, minimum width=3em},
  sum/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=6mm, inner sep=0pt,
                 node contents={$+$}},
  arr/.style = {-Stealth}
                        ]
% nodes in main branch organised in chain
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain, join=by arr}]
\coordinate (in) ;
\node (sum)     [sum];
\node (cntrl)   [box]   {$\dfrac{1}{Ls+R}$};
\node (kt)      [box]   {$k_t$};
\node (sys)     [box]   {\emph{system}};
\coordinate (out);
    \end{scope}
\node (dot)     [dot,
                 at={($(sys.east)!0.5!(out)$)},
                 label=above:$\Omega(s)$];
% feedback node
\node (fb)      [box, below=of kt]  {$k_e$};
% connections not consider in "join" macro
\draw[arr]  (dot) |- (fb)
            (fb)  -| (sum) node[pos=0.75, left] {$E(s)$}
                           node[pos=0.98, left] {$-$};
% labels as quotes on nodes connections
\path   (in)    to["$V(s)$"]    (sum)       
        (cntrl) to["$I(s)$"]    (kt) 
        (kt)    to["$T(s)$"]    (sys);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*:

- In `chains` is considered `positioning` library syntax, so with `node distance=6mm and 12mmm` is determined vertical distance between nodes (in main and feedback branch) and horizontal distance between nodes in main branch.
- styles of image elements are determined as options of `tikzpicture`. They can be collected in `tikzset` for example in preamble:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                positioning,
                quotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \tikzset{
  dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, outer sep=0pt,
                node contents={}},
  box/.style = {draw, minimum height=2em, minimum width=3em},
  sum/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=6mm, inner sep=0pt,
                 node contents={$+$}},
  arr/.style = {-Stealth}
        }
ment}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 6mm and 12mm,
  start chain = going right,
                        ]
% nodes in main branch
...
```